# Grayscale gnuplot with grouped boxplots

Tags: gnuplot, boxplot, eps

I need to create grouped boxplots, ideally using `gnuplot` exactly as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69810201/14618882).
However, I need a grayscale plot. Moreover, the output has to be an encapsulated Postscript (EPS) file.
When adding these two lines

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced 24
set output "fruit_prices.eps"
```

I get the following plot (I converted the EPS file to a PNG file because StackOverflow doesn't accept EPS files):

[image: Grayscale grouped boxplot example]

For some reason, all nine boxes have a different line style. I need the first box for Company A, B, and C to have the same style, and the same for the second and third box (matching the coloring in the original example).

How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default option for terminal `postscript eps` is `monochrome` and apparently you get only one grey fill color but differently dashed lines.

Without knowing details, you apparently have to set the option `color` and define your linetypes explicitly and use it in the plot command via `lt COL`.

**Script:** (with the data from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69810201/14618882))

```
### grouped boxplots
reset session
set terminal postscript eps color enhanced 24
set output "SO77584267.eps"

set linetype 1 lc rgb 0xcccccc dt 1
set linetype 2 lc rgb 0x777777 dt 1
set linetype 3 lc rgb 0x000000 dt 1

FILES     = 'A B C'
File(n)   = sprintf("Company %s.dat",word(FILES,n))
myXtic(n) = sprintf("Company %s",word(FILES,n))

set xlabel "Fruit prices"
set ylabel "Price"
set yrange [0:5]
set grid y

set key noautotitle
set style fill solid 0.3

N    = words(FILES)    # number of files
COLS = 3               # number of columns in file
PosX = 0               # x-position of boxplot

plot for [n=1:N] for [COL=1:COLS] PosX=PosX+1 File(n) u (PosX):COL w boxplot lt COL, \
     for [COL=1:COLS] File(1) u (NaN):COL w boxes lt COL ti columnhead, \
     for [n=1:N] File(1) u ((n-1)*COLS+COLS/2+1):(NaN):xtic(myXtic(n))
set output
### end of script
```

**Result:**

My GhostView as EPS viewer doesn't work with together with the latest version of GhostScript. So, I used IrfanView together with GhostScript, but I'm not sure whether the color representation is correct, e.g. if I set color to `black` or `0x000000`, I still get only a grey shade.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution works for me.

Comment: Ghostview has been unsupported for ages, and I'm afraid it doesn't like the altered version numbers. Ghostscript will itself display the rendered result though using the display device, so you don't actually need GhostView (or IrfanView). Note that display support on Linux relies on having X Window support.

Comment: @Kens thank your for this info. I didn't know and I never tried that Ghostscript can also display files itself. Good to know. Couldn't maybe the GS version number somehow be manipulated that Ghostview will accept it or will there be other incompatibilities? But related to the question, I don't understand why the output of "black" is not black, but grey. Is this a gnuplot thing or an EPS thing?

Comment: We could change the Ghostscript version number back, but how much effort can we reasonably be expected to expend on compatibility with an application which has been unsupported for years ? It is also true, as you say, that there would undoubtedly be other incompatibilities. Not sure exactly what but I know Ghostview rummages around in the PDF interpreter internals and that simply won't work any more (different interpreter). I'd have to see the EPS file to say any more about the output though.